# How to get the default Frame to use as parent component?

Tags: java, swing, window, joptionpane, look-and-feel

As in a `JOptionPane` I want to set a parent `Component` when sending a null value as the component parent.

> **parentComponent**:
>   Defines the Component that is to be the parent of this dialog box. It is used in two ways: the Frame that contains it is used as the Frame parent for the dialog box, and its screen coordinates are used in the placement of the dialog box. In general, the dialog box is placed just below the component. ***This parameter may be null, in which case a default Frame is used as the parent***, and the dialog will be centered on the screen (depending on the L&F).

That's how a `JOptionPane` works, now I want to do the same, but don't know how to get the default frame and set it as the parent to show a Notification. I'm using the `NotificationManager` to show a notification that is included in [WebLaF](http://weblookandfeel.com/) L&F, but when i try to show a notification before setVisible the `Frame` it throws me this error

"There is no visible windows to display notification"

It comes from here:`NotificationManager` class:method to get the window when sending a null component as parent

```
private static Window getDefaulShowForWindow ()
{
    final Window activeWindow = SwingUtils.getActiveWindow ();
    if ( activeWindow != null )
    {
        return activeWindow;
    }
    final Window[] allWindows = Window.getWindows ();
    if ( allWindows != null && allWindows.length > 0 )
    {
        return allWindows[ 0 ];
    }
    throw new RuntimeException ( "There is no visible windows to display notification" );
}
```

`SwingUtils` class: method `getActiveWindow()`

```
public static Window getActiveWindow ()
{
    final Window[] windows = Window.getWindows ();
    Window window = null;
    for ( final Window w : windows )
    {
        if ( w.isVisible () && w.isActive () && w.isFocused () )
        {
            window = w;
            break;
        }
    }
    return window;
}
```

So what I want to know is what does `JOptionPane` do(in code) when sending a null `Component` as parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at `JOptionPane`, it will eventually end up in `showOptionDialog(Component, Object, String, int, int, Icon, Object[], Object)`

In this method, when `parentComponent` is `null`, it calls `getRootFrame`.  This does some interesting work.  Basically it works with `SwingUtilities` to "find" a suitable `Frame` to use.  If one doesn't exist, it will frame a "shared" reference...

This is generated via `SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame`, which will (eventually) create a `Frame` called `SharedOwnerFrame`, which has overriden the `show` method so that it can never be displayed...

This is all done from within a package-private level, so you can't call any of this functionality yourself...

**Updated**

I should point out that the same instance of `SharedOwnerFrame` is used by all `JOptionPane`s

Comment: Can u give me any example or a link reference please

Comment: Crack open the source included with your JDK or if your using a IDE, follow the methods till you get that point

Comment: Well, actually i don't know how to do that, but thanks:)

Comment: Well, in netbeans, press <ctrl>+<left click> to "follow" the method

Comment: JOptionPane is derived JDialog, then isn't required thgis quite useless ZOO for that, (but see my next comment too)

Comment: @Mikle Garin please can you to test this OPs issue with WebLaF,

Comment: Actually, JOptionPane derives from `JComponent` :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes for hierarchy in APIs structure, sorry is always hidden in JDialogs farm :-), accesible etc.